# Python Syntax Error

Tags: python, django

Created a views.py method to get the data posted from an html form.
As well as getting the data I am trying to validate the check boxes.
However am being given a syntax error, but I don't understand why.

Code:

```
if request.POST:
    startdate = request.POST['startdate']
    enddate = request.POST['enddate']
    getlogs = 0
    if request.POST['getlogs'] = 'on':   << syntax error identified here
        getlogs = 1
```

Comment: -1 if you'd read the syntax error, it'd have told you exactly what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testing for equality requires two equals signs, like this:

```
if request.POST['getlogs'] == 'on':
```

Answer (score 7):

You want the equality operator.

```
if request.POST['getlogs'] == 'on':
```

`=` is not an operator in Python, as the assignment is a statement, not an expression.

Answer (score 2):

replace:

```
if request.POST['getlogs'] = 'on':
```

with

```
if request.POST['getlogs'] == 'on':
                           ^^
```

In python, one equal sign always means "make the left side take the value on the right side" and two always means "compare the left side with the right side".  The former is a statement, and illegal in the context of an `if` comparison expression.